# Read excel file and put into html Template

Tags: php, html-parsing, export-to-excel

I am trying to create a description builder with excel data. I want to use an predefined values in HTML template and want put the excel value in the location where the predefined values is appearing e.g.

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>ISBN</td>
     <td>{ISBN}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Publisher</td>
     <td>{Publisher}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Year</td>
     <td>{Year}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>About Book</td>
     <td>{AboutBook}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

HTML template can be pass from an physical HTML file or from a textarea.
I want the text to be replace in the curly braces with the excel data.
Headings in the excel file is same as the values in HTML template but the excel file can be change every time and its headings as well, there could be more headings in excel file from which only few of them are included in HTML template.
I am using excelreader to get the data from excel file

```
for ($j = 1; $j <= $data->sheets[0]['numCols']; $j++) {
    $xlshead[$j] = trim($data->sheets[0]['cells'][1][$j]);
}

foreach($xlshead as $hkey=>$hval) {
        $row[$hkey] = trim($hval);
    }
```

Now I have got the column number in array $row keys and the headings in the array $row values

i am using

```
for ($j = 1; $j <= $data->sheets[0]['numRows']-1; $j++) {
       str_replace(array_valyes($row),$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$j+1][array_$keys($row)],$_POST['strhtmltemplate'])
}
```

No i don't know how to get the exact key in replace function.
please help me.

Comment: Have you considered exporting it as CSV and using `fgetcsv` to parse it? It'd be simpler

Comment: thanks Martin but i have done that. i have replaced variables of template file with the excel reader string e.g.
`foreach($xlshead as $hkey=>$hval) {
  $row['<?php echo $data->sheets[0][\'cells\'][$j+1]['.$hkey.']; ?>'] = "{".trim($hval)."}";
 }`
and wrote in a separate file than did a print with ob_start and fetched the content to a new file and exported in excel.
Next time i will try the fgetcsv as in this project there are many things which not be suitable for csv format as it contains formulas and other things as well. so we have to export the file into csv everytime..
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete code i have done for my project

```
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
$filename = $_SESSION['filename'];
$data->read(ROOT.$filename);

$xlshead = array();

for ($j = 1; $j <= $data->sheets[0]['numCols']; $j++) {
    $xlshead[$j] = trim($data->sheets[0]['cells'][1][$j]);
}

$TotalRecord = $data->sheets[0]['numRows']-1;
$row = array();

foreach($xlshead as $hkey=>$hval) {
    $row['<?php echo $data->sheets[0][\'cells\'][$j+1]['.$hkey.']; ?>'] = "{".trim($hval)."}";
}

function _loadFile($filename)
{
    $contents = '';
    if ( file_exists($filename ) )
    {
        ob_start();
        require_once $filename;
        $contents = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
    }
    return $contents;
}

$datafile = session_id();
$writedata = "";

$writedata .= str_replace(array_values($row),array_keys($row),$_SESSION['template']);

$myFile = $datafile.".php";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $writedata);
fclose($fh);

$showdata = _loadFile("code.php");
$_SESSION['finaldata'] = $showdata;
```

**code.php**

```
require_once 'Excel/reader.php';

$datafile = session_id();

if(isset($_SESSION['filename'])) {
    $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
    $filename = $_SESSION['filename'];
    $data->read(ROOT.$filename);

    for ($j = 1; $j <= $data->sheets[0]['numRows']-1; $j++) {
        include($datafile.".php");
        echo '--br--';
    }
}
```

**Finally exporting the file in to excel**

```
<?php
session_start();
$filename ="Downloaded.xls";
header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);

$dataarr = explode("--br--",$_SESSION['finaldata']);

?>
<table>
<?php 

$dataarr = explode("--br--",$_SESSION['finaldata']);

foreach($dataarr as $res) {
    echo "<tr><td>".htmlentities($res)."</td></tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: instead of making an answer with your code, you're better off just clicking the "edit" button on your answer.